# How to compare numbers in columns

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have data in libreoffice like

```
ColumnA ColumnB
504231  504109
504109  504201
504201  
504299
```

like so much data Then I want output like

```
ColumnA ColumnB
504231  
504109  504109
504201  504201
504299
```

I tried `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$3;A1)>0;A1;"")` this formula works when comparing strings . I tried in similar but am not getting result

How to achieve this output please let me know

Comment: question was edited please see

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP solved the problem and included the solution in a follow-up question asked the next day: http://superuser.com/questions/731257/how-to-compare-number-with-number-in-other-column-and-get-corresponding-value

Answer (score 0):

This VBa does what you want...

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim numberOfRows As Integer
numberOfRows = 10            'Update this number from 10 to the number of rows you are using

   For rowNumberB = 1 To numberOfRows
        Dim cellToCheck As String
        valueToCheck = Range("B" & rowNumberB).Value ' get the value from B column
        For rowNumberA = 1 To numberOfRows
            If Range("A" & rowNumberA).Value = valueToCheck Then
                Range("C" & rowNumberA).Value = valueToCheck 'assign the new value to col C on the correct row (has to be on C otherwise we could over write existing values in B
                Range("B" & rowNumberB).Value = "" 'delete the original value from col B
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Now we have to move everything from col C to B
    For rowNumberC = 1 To numberOfRows
        Range("B" & rowNumberC).Value = Range("C" & rowNumberC).Value ' copy from C to B
        Range("C" & rowNumberC).Value = "" ' Delete the value from C
    Next

End Sub
```

You didn't mention what would happen if the items in Column B came before or After the value in Column A, nor what to do with duplicates in either column. Well, the code above will resolve all of that. See screen shots below.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by the questioner himself in [his next question](https://superuser.com/q/731257/260802):

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0))`