# How to compare number with number in other column and get corresponding value

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

If suppose I have data like

```
column1 column2 
504231  504109  
504109  504201  
504201      
504299
```

then I used the following formula `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0))` it works fine and it producess following result

```
column1 column2 column3
504231  504109  
504109  504201  504109
504201          504201
504299
```

Now I have data like

```
column1 column2 column3
504231   504109 smith
504109   504201 scott
504201      
504299
```

then I want ouput like

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
504231  504109  smith       
504109  504201  scott   504109  smith
504201                  504201  scott
504299
        **OR**
column1 column2 column3
504231      
504109  504109  smith
504201  504201  scott
504299
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this for the names column (column5):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$5,2,0))
```

This gives the following result, you wanted:

[image: results]

Explanation: You have to extend the lookup-matrix to column3 (`C`). And you need to pick the name from the second column of this matrix (`2`). Maybe have a look at [this VLOOKUP-Tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2010functions/qt/2010-05-09-excel-2010-vlookup-function.htm).

Comment: Any idea why this was rated down? Did I make an error? Have you tried the solution @user3341177?